# Display whole form on button click/submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form. On submit of the form I want to display the whole form, but it currently isn't doing so. Here is my code:

```js
function Openform()
{
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = '';
}
```

```html
<div id = "form1" style = "display:none">
<form  id="formirri" method="post" action="" target="_parent">
       <br/><br/>
    <div id="demo">
    <table width="230px" align="center" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);"><tr><td colspan=1></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="close-classic"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<input id="dynamic" name="Irrigation Form" type="button" value="Calulation Form" ; onclick = "Openform();"
  style="overflow:hidden;padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 3px;font-size: 8.5pt; width:200px ; background-color: #E7FCCA; font-weight: bold; ">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in style.Change like below:

```
function Openform()
{
document.getElementById('form1').style.display = '';
}

<div style = "display:none">
```

display and visibility both are different.

**display**:none will not be available in the page and does not occupy any space.

**visibility**:hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before.

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "form1" style = "display:none">
<form  id="formirri" method="post" action="" target="_parent">
       <br/><br/>
    <div id="demo">
    <table width="230px" align="center" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);"><tr><td colspan=1></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="close-classic"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: changes does not effect the error . still  my whole form does not display o button click. see my edited snippet

Comment: you are not closing the form

Comment: this helped you?

Comment: strangely no. but my form is not displaying. is there any other way to do runtime calculation.

Comment: command all the html other than that form and div tag.Then check.

Comment: This is working for me.make sure you have kept javascript function in <script></script>

Answer (score 3):

One mistake you made here is you forgot to close your `<form>` tag, First use `display:none` in your form tag then using `onclick()` change it's style to `display:block`.

Try this

```js
function Openform(){
  document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
  <div style = "Visibility = hidden">
<form  id="form1" method="post" action="" target = "_parent" style="display: none" ><br><br>
    <div id="demo">
      <table width="230px" align="center" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);">
        <tr>
          <td colspan=1>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#" class="close-classic">2</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
</form>

<input id="dynamic" name="Irrigation Form" type="button" value="Calulation Form" ; onclick = "Openform();"
  style="overflow:hidden;padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 3px;font-size: 8.5pt; width:200px ; background-color: #E7FCCA; font-weight: bold; ">
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function Openform()
{
document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "form1" style = "visibility:hidden">
<form  id="formirri" method="post" action="" target="_parent">
   <br/><br/>
<div id="demo">
<table width="230px" align="center" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);"><tr><td colspan=1></td></tr>
<tr>
   <td><a href="#" class="close-classic"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
function Openform() {
  document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post" action="" target="_parent" style="display:none;">
  <br><br>
  <div id="demo">
    <table width="230px" align="center" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);">
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="close-classic"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
<input id="dynamic" name="Irrigation Form" type="button" value="Calulation Form" ; onclick="Openform();" style="overflow:hidden;padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 3px;font-size: 8.5pt; width:200px ; background-color: #E7FCCA; font-weight: bold; ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your all code is correct except few closing HTML tags.

```js
function Openform()
{
    alert("Openform clicked!");
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = '';
}
```

```html
<div id = "form1" style = "display:none">
<form  id="formirri" method="post" action="" target="_parent">
       <br/><br/>
    <div id="demo">
    <table width="230px" align="center" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);">
    <tr><td colspan=1> Welcome User</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="close-classic">I am the second line</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<input id="dynamic" name="Irrigation Form" type="button" value="Calulation Form" ; onclick = "Openform();"
  style="overflow:hidden;padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 3px;font-size: 8.5pt; width:200px ; background-color: #E7FCCA; font-weight: bold; ">
```

**Happy coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your function like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('id');
 elem.style.display = 'none'; // hide
 elem.style.display = 'block'; // show - use this for block elements (div, p)
 elem.style.display = 'inline'; // show - use this for inline elements (span, a)
```

or style.visibility will actually make the div still be there, but be "all empty" or "all white"

```
 elem.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // hide, but lets the element keep its size
 elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

If you are using jQuery, you can do it even easier as long as you want to set the display property:

```
$(elem).hide();
$(elem).show();
```